# can't install "npm install -g yo" global only local.

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, yo

im triying to install jhipster but I can't install

```
npm install -g yo
```

im getting this

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version
✖ yo version

Your yo version is outdated.

Upgrade to the latest version by running:
npm install -g yo@latest


Found potential issues on your machine :(
+ yo@2.0.5
```

but if I run

```
 npm install yo
```

im not getting any problem

im using 
npm -v
6.4.1
node -v
v10.13.0
and macOS Mojave 10.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try a different way I run

```
yarn global add yo
```

then

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin):$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin"
```

and

```
yo jhipster
```

now jhipster is finally working